# Change background color of row with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssf

I try to use `Apache POI` to change background colors of cells in a row. I use following code to handle it in `xls` file, but there aren't any changes in file after execution.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);                
r = sheet.getRow(5);
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
r.setRowStyle(style);
```

Comment: That code doesn't alter the file itself in any way. Is that all the code?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : I just added following lines after these, but style is not present in xls.
        `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
        wb.write(fileOut);`

Comment: Also call `wb.close();` and `fileOut.close();` jsut to be sure (unless you use `try-with-resource`). BTW, how do you get `sheet`? You create a new `HSSFWorkbook` but never call `wb.getSheet()` or `wb.createSheet()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : I use this, sorry, I didn't paste it: `HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);`

Comment: Update the question with the full code

Comment: I think you just need to include `style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);` before applying the style

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : This helped, but red background applied only on part of the cells in this row, so isn't from column A.

Comment: If you call `r.createCell(0);` after `r.setRowStyle(style);` it will overwrite the row style for that cell. It might be worth it to try to set the `rowstyle` after you finished creating new cells in the row

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : I do these changes on an existing xls file, so cells are created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style for cells has to be defined like this.

```
HSSFCellStyle tCs = wb.createCellStyle();
tCs.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
tCs.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
```

It has to be applied each cells, which needed this style.

```
for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(5).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
   sheet.getRow(i).getCell(k).setCellStyle(tCs);
}
```